# How to solve the Cauchy problem?

Tags: cauchy-problem

I have a task that looks like
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = 2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + u + 3e^{t},\, u\left(x, 0\right)=\sin{x}$$

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: Just a thought. Set $v(x,s)=\mathcal{L}\Big(u(x,t)\Big)$ where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the Laplace transform. If you apply $\mathcal{L}$ to your PDE and rearrange terms you get $$2v_{xx}+v_{x}+(1-s)v=-\sin(x)+\frac{3}{1-s}$$ where $s>1$. The differential of this transformed PDE only depends on $x$ and can be solved using standard techniques by treating $s$ as a constant. Once you have $v(x,s)$ you can using $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ to retrieve $u(x,t)$.

Comment: For example, the PDE $$u_{xx}+e^yu=0$$ has general solution $$u(x,y)=f(y)\cos\Big(e^{y/2}x\Big)+g(y)\sin\Big(e^{y/2}x\Big)$$ by treating $y$ as constant. Here $f,g$ are arbitrary functions.

Comment: Thanks! :))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We continue Matthew Pilling solution:
Using Laplace transform method we get ode
$$2v_{xx}+v_{x}+(1-s)v=-\sin(x)+\frac{3}{1-s}$$
Particular solution is
$$v=\frac{s\sin x+\sin x+\cos x}{s^2+2s+2}+\frac{3}{(s-1)^2}$$
Final solution of Cauchy problem is
$$u(x,t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}v=e^{-t}\sin(x+t)+3te^t$$

Comment: Can you say please why
$$\frac{s\sin{x}+\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{s^{2}+2s+2}$$
is
$$e^{-t}\sin{\left(x+t\right)}$$?

Comment: Sorry, i understood. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Some details:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\ \frac{3}{(s-1)^2}\right)=3te^t$$
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\ \frac{1}{s^2+2s+2}\right)=e^{-t}\sin t$$
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\ \frac{s}{s^2+2s+2}\right)=e^{-t}(\cos t-\sin t)$$